# Prevent height from cutting off hover content

Tags: html, css

In React, I have a container that has a fixed height and a tooltip component that makes another div appear once it's hovered. However, The fixed height is currently cutting it off:

[image]

The tooltip is positioned absolutely as well:

[image]

if I remove the height, then everything just collapses. I'm also unable to increase the height of this component further, unfortunately. Are there any alternatives around this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in a snippet, please...

Comment: You should use `position: fixed` in this case, since you need it above anything else. Absolute will be relative to the parent div, which is causing it to crop a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the relevant code, I can only make two guesses:

**1. The container is cropping the content**

In this case you should try setting the overflow to allow extending over boundaries.
Try setting `overflow: visible` to the container.

**2. The subsequent container is being placed over the tooltip:**

In this case you should try setting a css `z-index` to the tooltip and the subsequent container, in order to reposition the tooltip over the container.
Something like this:

```
.tooltip{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}

.subsequentContainer{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```